# implementing snmp on stellaris microcontroller

Tags: c#

The main aim of our task is to ping the network device through the LM3s6965 (Cortex device or kit) ,using SNMP protocol .
If you can provide us the sample code to PINng  device through LM3s6965 kit ,then it will be very helpful.
Please suggest example to proceed for the same .

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are in the wrong way. You need to implement .NET Micro Framework using .NET Micro Framework 4.0 Porting Kit and THEN start to look for chunks of C# code for SNMP.
It is much easier to implement SNMP using C in my opinion.

You may find useful this thread: [FreeRTOS + lwIP + LM3S6965](http://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/stellaris_arm_cortex-m3_microcontroller/f/473/t/44435.aspx)